# Count with LIMIT clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have used below query to count total records

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as tot FROM last as l JOIN box m on m.id = l.id 
     WHERE m.st > l.st AND l.id = 23 LIMIT 5;
```

But this query still returns total count as 20  rows even when i put limit 5, How to restrict it to 5 . is there any performance issue using count(*) ? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks information to diagnose the problem. Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: the Limit keyword limits the number of rows returned, Count(*) as in your example returns 1 row which is less than your limit of 5. 

Consider using 

RANK ( ) OVER ( [ partition_by_clause ] order_by_clause )

Comment: Do you want to count at most 5 rows?  or what?  `LIMIT` is one of the last clauses evaluated (after `ORDER BY`, which is after `GROUP BY`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need inner query for your purposes:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as tot 
FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM last as l JOIN box m on m.id = l.id 
   WHERE m.st > l.st AND l.id = 23 LIMIT 5) AS `t1`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Count makes your query returning 1 row. Limit keeps the first 5 row, but you have already 1 row only.

You should use limit in an internal query and count in an outer. Something like this:

```
select count(*) as tot from (
  SELECT 1 FROM last as l JOIN box m on m.id = l.id 
     WHERE m.st > l.st AND l.id = 23 LIMIT 5
) x
```